# Fundamental theorem of calculus 1 where integrand is a 2nd order partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I have a function $b(x,y)$ such that $b(x,0)=0$.

Now, suppose I wish to evaluate the following integral: (Note that $b$ is continuous almost everywhere but it is assumed that it is integrable. Also, the second order partial derivative of $b$ is continuous hence we can interchange the partial derivatives)

$\int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 b(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} dy$.

Is this correct?

$\int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 b(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} dy = \frac{\partial b(x,1)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial b(x,0)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial b(x,1)}{\partial x}$

since $b(x,0)=0$?

I'm unsure as $\frac{\partial b(x,0)}{\partial x}=0$ seems to involve an interchange of 2 operators. Under what conditions is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me. And what "interchange of operators" are you talking about at the end?

Comment: Hi @vonbrand , what I meant was, it's either you compute the derivative $\partial b(x,y) /\partial x$ first and substitute $y=0$ or you can subsitute $y=0$ first and take the derivative. So which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be suspicious in general, but this is fine. There is no swapping of operations; there is only one operation, which is [taking a partial derivative at a point]. We have
$$\frac{\partial b(x,0)}{\partial x} := \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{b(x+h,0)-b(x,0)}{t} \equiv 0$$
since $y$ is held fixed during the limiting process.